# MVC ASP.net file upload : filepath is empty after submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, httppostedfilebase

I've this **HTML**:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "BulkUpload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { %>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UploadFile, new { @type = "file" }) %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UploadFile, "*") %>
    <%= Html.Button("submit", "Upload", null) %>
<% } %>
```

And this **Model**:

```
public class BulkUploadVM
{
    [DisplayName("File to import")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase UploadFile { get; set; }
}
```

And this **Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(BulkUploadVM model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var stream = model.UploadFile.InputStream;

        // Process stream ...
    }

    return View("Index", model);
}
```

The upload file is correctly posted to the Controller, but when the Controller returns the View with the model (which has a valid UploadFile), the filepath is empty on the page ?

Is this default behavior ? Or Am I missing something ?

Comment: What do you expect the filepath to be?

Comment: The same file path I entered / choose using the 'Browse' button.

Comment: This value is not available to the server, so it can't be set on a repost.

Comment: @Oded : model.UploadFile.FileName See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.filename.aspx

Comment: Most browsers do **not** provide this information for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already described by Oded, it's **not** possible to set the value from the file upload input element because of security reasons.

See [RFC 1867](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html) and [this link](http://www.htmlhelp.org/reference/html40/forms/input.html).

*The file input type creates a field through which users can upload files from their local computer or network. The VALUE attribute specifies the name of the initial file, but it is typically ignored by browsers as a security precaution.*

Answer (score 0):

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", new { BulkUploadVM = Model }, 
               FormMethod.Post,   new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { %>

    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UploadFile, new { @type = "file" }) %>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UploadFile, "*") %>

    <input type="submit" value="Finish" />

    <% } %>
```

Set the routeValues object

```
new { BulkUploadVM = Model }
```